# SQL - Rewrite MSSQL query to Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE (0 < (SELECT COUNT(Table_2.ID)
            FROM Table_2 inner join Table_3
                on Table_2.ID= Table_3.A_ID AND Table_3.B_ID = Table_1.ID))
```

It works fine on Microsoft SQL, but I have to write it to Oracle sql, where it doesn't work, because Table_1 is not in the subquery.

I tried to rewrite it, but with the rewrited form it gives 20060 rows, while the original sql has just 497 rows in it's result.

One of the rewrited ones:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE (0 < (SELECT COUNT(Table_2.ID)
            FROM Table_2 inner join Table_3
                on  Table_2.ID = Table_3.A_ID
                AND Table_3.B_ID IN (SELECT Table_1.ID FROM Table_1)) )
```

Can you please give me some help how to rewrite it properly, and what is the reason of the larger resultset?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work in Oracle.

Comment: That's not a good T-SQL query to begin with. The queries suggested by @jarlh would perform far better because they join with the outer table directly. This query joins, then calculates a count that does nothing more than validate the results of the join

Comment: What are the field types? Are the IDs numbers or strings? If they are strings, do they contain trailing spaces perhaps? Are the *data* the same? Why assume that 20060 is wrong? Did the query return bad matches or duplicates?

Comment: The field types were irrelevant in this case. 
The data is the same, of course, because the result with 497 rows and the another one with 20060 rows are both from the MSSQL db. The original (497) and the rewrited one (20060). I just wanted to show that the rewrited sql is not equivalent with the original one, and I needed the equivalent one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *standard* SQL, although I would put the correlation clause in a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(Table_2.ID)
           FROM Table_2 INNER JOIN
                Table_3
                ON Table_2.ID = Table_3.A_ID 
           WHERE Table_3.B_ID = Table_1.ID
          );
```

This should work in both databases.

However, I would write this using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table_2 INNER JOIN
                   Table_3
                   ON Table_2.ID = Table_3.A_ID 
              WHERE Table_3.B_ID = Table_1.ID
             );
```

This should also work on *any* database.

If your queries are getting *different* results,  the most likely reason is that the data is different in the two databases.

Answer (score 1):

Does a basic `EXISTS` query work?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Table_2 inner join Table_3
                on Table_2.ID = Table_3.A_ID AND Table_3.B_ID = Table_1.ID)
```

Or `IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table_1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT Table_2.ID 
             FROM Table_2 inner join Table_3
                on Table_2.ID = Table_3.A_ID)
```

Comment: It gives the right resultset in MSSQL, but it still won't work in oracle sql, because of the same reason.

Comment: @SummerFlower, very strange. This is very basic functionality. I'll give you an IN query in an hour.